# Deployment issue for a GWT App on JBOSS 5.0.0 GA

Tags: gwt, deployment, war, jboss5.x

Thanks in advance for your help. I am trying to deploy a GWT App (.war file) to a JBOSS 5.0.0 GA AS. The app deploys fine on a Tomcat 7 servlet container.

The following is the interesting part of the server log:

```
14:53:46,051 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Parse: name=vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/portal.wa
r state=Not Installed mode=Manual requiredState=Parse
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error creating managed object for vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/portal.w
ar
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:337)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:297)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:269)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.deploy(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:230)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:545)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.loadProfile(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:304)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:205)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:405)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:209)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:547)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to parse source: null
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:203)
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:168)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.JBossXBDeployerHelper.parse(JBossXBDeployerHelper.java:199)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.JBossXBDeployerHelper.parse(JBossXBDeployerHelper.java:170)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.SchemaResolverDeployer.parse(SchemaResolverDeployer.java:132)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.SchemaResolverDeployer.parse(SchemaResolverDeployer.java:118)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parseAndInit(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:256)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parse(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:239)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:330)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1002)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:997)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:997)
        at org.jboss.classloader.plugins.loader.ClassLoaderToLoaderAdapter.getResource(ClassLoaderToLoaderAdapter.java:120)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.ClassLoaderDomain.getResourceFromParent(ClassLoaderDomain.java:475)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.ClassLoaderDomain.beforeGetResource(ClassLoaderDomain.java:431)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.getResource(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:400)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.getResource(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1116)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.getResource(BaseClassLoader.java:410)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:1192)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SecuritySupport$6.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SecuritySupport.getResourceAsStream(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.findJarServiceProvider(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.createObject(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.createObject(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.<init>(SaxJBossXBParser.java:92)
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.UnmarshallerImpl.<init>(UnmarshallerImpl.java:56)
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.UnmarshallerFactory$UnmarshallerFactoryImpl.newUnmarshaller(UnmarshallerFactory.java:96)
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.metadata.XsdAnnotation.unmarshal(XsdAnnotation.java:53)
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.sunday.unmarshalling.XsdBinder.bindAttribute(XsdBinder.java:916)
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.sunday.unmarshalling.XsdBinder.bindComplexType(XsdBinder.java:693)
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.sunday.unmarshalling.XsdBinder.bindType(XsdBinder.java:508)
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.sunday.unmarshalling.XsdBinder.bindElement(XsdBinder.java:1143)
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.sunday.unmarshalling.XsdBinder.bindParticle(XsdBinder.java:1025)
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.sunday.unmarshalling.XsdBinder.bindModelGroupParticles(XsdBinder.java:1208)
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.sunday.unmarshalling.XsdBinder.bindParticle(XsdBinder.java:1016)
```

.....

Thanks again.

Comment: +1 and Kudos. "Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError" question on stackoverflow.com !!!!!!

Comment: What is your targeted jdk?

Comment: The targeted jdk is 1.6.0_14.

Comment: I think is probably a jar confusion issue. I am currently following this path. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If I recall correctly jboss 5.0.0 is targeted for 1.5 jdk , you are correct that its probally a class loading issue ... https://community.jboss.org/wiki/whydoigetjavalangclasscastexceptionorgapachexercesparsersxincludeawareparserconfigurationinas-5 might be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that was caused by one of my configuration files being named persistence.xml, which is a reserved filename in Jboss 5